# Async function in NodeJS EventEmitter on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, eventemitter

I have an AWS Lambda application built upon an external library that contains an EventEmitter. On a certain event, I need to make a HTTP request. So I was using this code (simplified):

```
myEmitter.on("myEvent", async() => {
    setup();
    await doRequest();
    finishingWork();
});
```

What I understand that happens is this:

My handler is called, but as soon as the `doRequest` function is called, a Promise is returned and the EventEmitter continues with the next handlers. When all that is done, the work of the handler can continue (`finishingWork`).

This works locally, because my NodeJS process keeps running and any remaining events on the eventloop are handled. The strange thing is that this doesn't seem to work on AWS Lambda. Even if `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` is set to true.

In my logging I can see my handler enters the `doRequest` function, but nothing after I call the library to make the HTTP call (`request-promise` which uses `request`). And the code doesn't continue when I make another request (which I would expect if `callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` is set to false, which it isn't).

Has anyone experienced something similar and know how to perform an ansynchronous HTTP request in the handler of a NodeJS event emitter, on AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how to solve this, feel free to add another answer. But for now, the "solution" for us was to put the eventhandler code elsewhere in our codebase. This way, it is executed asynchronously.

We were able to do that because there is only one place where the event is emitted, but the eventhandler way would have been a cleaner solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar issue as well, my event emitter logs all events normally until running into async function. It works fine in ECS but not in Lambda, as event emitter runs synchronously but Lambda will exit once the response is returned.

At last, I used [await-event-emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-event-emitter) to solve the problem.

```
await emitter.emit('onUpdate', ...);
```